# Creating an interaction varible with marks and submission date in regression with student performance as dependent variable in regression?

Tags: variables, regression, interaction

I am running a regression model where dependent variable is student performance. The independent variables are assignment marks and date of submission of assignment.  I am not sure how to include date of submission in my model? Should I create an interaction varible with marks and submission date? Is there a way where both quality of work done and the speed at which it is done be included in model together and is also easy to interpret?

I have used marks and date of submission as 2 variables. I want to create an interaction varible but I'm not sure how to logically combine these two.

Comment: What language/framework are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using python.